# Number of installed keyboard layouts in Linux Mint Qiana

Tags: keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I cannot add more than 4 keyboard layouts in Linux Mint Qiana running Cinnamon. Is that normal?
Is there such limitation or I am doing something wrong?

[image: keyboard layouts applet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known [issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3146) and there's [request](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3212) to fix it.

There was a limitation (feature) of four keyboard layouts allowed in gnome-control-center and gnome-settings-daemon, but in recent releases it has been removed. However, Mint developers have not merged this changes into cinnamon yet.

**UPDATE**

After looking more into this issue, it seems there's bug in X server and it is present in all DEs. I only found a workaround [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107945/cant-add-more-than-four-keyboard-layouts).

**UPDATE #2**

This issue is fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well, is this issue related only to Gnome and Mint Cinnamon? Can you propose me distro with the lack of this limitation? Or DE? Does other Mint DEs (Mate, KDE, Xfce) have proper layout facilities?

Comment: Yes, it's related only to them.

Comment: In Mint Xfce I had the same issue. It's undoubted. And hence it appears my question: it's Mint core-related problem or DE-related problem?

Comment: After looking more into this issue, it seems there's bug in X server and it is present in all DEs. I only found a workaround [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107945/cant-add-more-than-four-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: Well, X server is used commonly (in all Linux distros). Thus, you insisted on that there is no distros without this problem? Nothing? I heard, that KDE is free of it.

Comment: I have tried in KDE on my FreeBSD, there are still 4-layout limitation. BUT I tried also ubuntu 14.04 and seems that it is fixed there [link](http://i.imgur.com/Ki6FCsn.png). Also I heard that it is fixed in latest Fedora, but I can't check if it's true.

Comment: Ubuntu is confirmed yesterday, but is not appreciated by me:((. Fedora is to be tested soon)) I am awaiting for your experiences nevertheless.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 19 (cinnamon) and still have the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I want to answer my question myself.

This bug affects:

1. Linux Mint
2. openSUSE 13.2
3. Mandriva
4. Gentoo
5. Slackware 14.1
6. ArchLinux
7. Debian
8. Elementary OS
9. Fedora 21 XFCE
10. Fedora 21 MATE
11. Xubuntu 14.10

This bug doesn't affect:

1. Ubuntu 14.10
2. Fedora 21 Workstation

Further updates and corrections are welcome!