# Assign hotkey to single keyboard layout in LXDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, lxde

Well, the question is following: can I assign separate keyboard shortcut to every layout I have?
Exactly like in Windows we can assign Ctrl-1, Ctrl-2 and so on, to any layout.
Question appeared after my great disappointment of Linux which I have thoroughly described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182486/number-of-installed-keyboard-layouts-in-linux-mint-qiana).
And in Arch (LXDE) I noticed that any number of layouts was available but **simultaneous switching** was possible only between 4 of them.
It doesn't matter if you offer another distro . Archlinux is not the stumbling block.